# cannot pass the input field value to service in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-services

contact-bar.component.ts

```
saveContacts(): void{
var contact = new Contact({});
contact.id = 1;
contact.name = 
(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("contactName")).value;
contact.mobile = parseInt((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("contactMobile")).value);
this.contactService.saveContact(contact);
}
```

contact.service.ts

```
saveContact(contact: Contact) {
    var contacts: Array<Contact> = 
JSON.parse(LocalStorage.getItem("contacts"));
    contacts.push(contact);
    localStorage.setItem("contacts", JSON.stringify(contacts));
}
```

> Error: Cannot read property 'push' of null

Comment: How is that related to Angular2? Obviously `JSON.parse(LocalStorage.getItem("contacts"));` doesn't return an array, but `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly regarding your error**: you are receiving `Cannot read property 'push' of null` because you are trying to get the contact data (through **localstoarge**) which is not there. That's why while pushing the data into the array you're prompted with that error.

However, There are some issues in your code which need to be fixed.

1. **Remove this line:**
   `var contacts: Array<Contact> = JSON.parse(LocalStorage.getItem("contacts"));`
2. **Instead of sending data as an array try the following:**

**Code:**

```
var contact =  {
    contact.id : 1;   
    contact.name:(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("contactName")).value;  
    contact.mobile: parseInt((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("contactMobile")).value);
    }

this.contactService.saveContact(contact);

**contact.service.ts**

saveContact(contact: any) {
    localStorage.setItem("contacts", JSON.stringify(contact));
}
```